# She began her career, winning 15 awards

Tags: subordinate-clauses

1. *She began her acting career in hollywood, **winning 15 awards** for her work between 2008 and 2012.*

Q: Does sentence 1) sound like *she won 15 awards first and **then** began her acting career* or is the sentence correct as it is?

Comment: It's simply not possible for anybody to win 15 awards for something they haven't done yet. In terms of formal syntax, *winning* should probably be replaced with *and she won*, but I can't see anybody misinterpreting what is being said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, it would be impossible for someone to win awards for something before they started, and yet your sentence does sound a little odd because the second statement reads as a dependent clause.

It would be clearer if you wrote:

> She began her acting career in Hollywood **and went on to win** 15 awards for her work between 2008 and 2012.